# A simple question on forward and backward invariant sets

Tags: dynamical-systems, invariant-theory

A subset $A\subset X$ is forward invariant if $f^{t}(A)\subset A$ for all $t\ge 0$ and backward invariant if $f^{-t}(A)\subset A$ for all $t\ge 0$.

I want to show that the complement of a forward invariant set is backward invariant (and vice-versa).

So the complement of $A$ is $X\setminus A$.

We have $f^{-t}(X\setminus A)=(f^{t})^{-1}(X\setminus A)...\subset X\setminus A$ for all $t\ge 0$.

How do I fill in the space between those dots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a simple reductio ad absurdum works here. Suppose that $X \setminus A$ is not backward invariant. It means that exist $x^{\ast} \in (X \setminus A)$ and $ t^{\ast} \in \mathbb{R_{+}}$ such that $f^{-t^{\ast}}(x^{\ast}) \notin (X\setminus A)$. From this follows that $f^{-t^{\ast}}(x^{\ast}) \in A$ and since $A$ is forward invariant $f^{t^{\ast}} \bigl ( f^{-t^{\ast}}(x^{\ast}) \bigr )$ is also in $A$. Therefore, $x^{\ast} \in A$, which is the contradiction.

Comment: How do you derive this part - "since $A$ is forward invariant $f^{t^{\ast}}(f^{-t^{\ast}}(x^{\ast}))$ is also in $A$"?

Comment: It's just another way to say "$f^t(A) \subset A$ for all $t \geqslant 0$". So if we take any point $x \in A$ and any $t \geqslant 0$  then $f^t(x) \in A$.